# Graph theory: Are DFS forests that correspond to a graph isomorphic?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

For a graph G, it may have many different DFS forests if we select different starting vertex or choose different unexplored edges. So we can construct many auxiliary graphs of G . Whether all auxiliary graphs of G are isomorphic with each other? Justify your answer.

I know what does it mean for a graph to be isomorphic but i don't know how to prove this is right or i can't think of a counter example for it

Please help

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [maths.se]

Answer (score 1):

No they are not isomorphic :

consider the following graph :

[image]

The following two DFS forests belong to it while obviously they aren't isomorphic :
[image]